# Can someone explain why replace isn't working for me

Tags: python, replace

I need to remove extra spaces in a sentences. The sentence is `"I  like   python"` and I need to make `"I like python"`. So I used replace like this:

```
>>>
>>> sentence="I  like   python"
>>> def checkio(element):
        newelement=element.replace("  ", " ") and element.replace("   ", " ")
        return newelement

>>> checkio(sentence)
'I  like python'
>>>
```

And you see, the result is `"I  like python"` even though I (think) I told it to replace `"  "` with `" "`. Can someone clear it up for me why this didn't work?

Comment: Instead of linking to an image, copy and paste your source code into your post, using the code formatting features provided.

Comment: That’s not what `and` does. If you want to replace from the result, use `element.replace("  ", " ").replace("   ", " ")`. But this isn’t the right way to do it anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted to do:

```
def checkio(element):
    newelement = element.replace("  ", " ").replace("   ", " ")
    return newelement
```

You could even shorten this to

```
def checkio(element):
    return element.replace("  ", " ").replace("   ", " ")
```

However, what if you wanted to replace an arbitrary number of spaces?  It is better to split the sentence on any number of spaces, and then join it back together with a single space.  To do this, you would use

```
def checkio(element):
    return " ".join(element.split())
```

The `split` method takes a string and separates it into a list.  With no argument, it separates on spaces:

```
>>> "I    like  python".split()
["I", "like", "python"]
```

The `join` method takes a list and makes a string out of it, using the string in between the elements of the list:

```
>>> ' '.join(["I", "like", "python"])
"I like python"
>>> '__HELP__'.join(["I", "like", "python"])
"I__HELP__like__HELP__python"
```

**Why your original attempt failed**

The line

```
newelement = element.replace("  ", " ") and element.replace("   ", " ")
```

was not doing what you expect because it was using the "truthiness" of strings.  The `and` operator looks at logical things.  In python, all strings except `""` are considered `True`.
The you can use this to do something called "short-circuiting", which is what you did.

When you use `and`, both the left and right statement must be true for it to evaluate to `True`.  If the left part is `False`, there is no reason to move on to the right part and evaluation stops there (aka "short-circuiting").  If it is true, then it needs to check the right side to see if the whole statement is true.  You can exploit this fact to return the left statement if it is false, or right if the left is true:

```
>>> a = "a" and "b"
>>> a
"b"
>>> a = "" and "b"
>>> a
""
>>> # It works oppositely with "or"
>>> a = "a" or "b"
>>> a
"a"
>>> a = "" or "b"
>>> a
"b"
```

`element.replace("  ", " ")` returns a string, and so does `element.replace("   ", " ")`.  Since the strings evaluate to `True`, you are essentially only ever returning the right statement of the `and`.

This is not a common use of logical operatiors in python (it is more often used in other languages, though)

Answer (score 2):

How about using this to remove extra whitespace:

```
" ".join(sentence.split())
```

If you want, you can package this as a function:

```
def checkio(element):
    return " ".join(element.split())
```

#### The reason why your approach fails is in your `and` statement.

Python first evaluates `element.replace("  ", " ")`, which gives `"I like  python"`, a `True` statement.

Since this is true, Python continues with the next statement, and **returns that value**

The next statement is `element.replace("   ", " ")`, which itself evaluates to `"I  like python"`

Finally, it sets this value to `newelement`, which your function returns

Comment: This is one way to write the function, but the question is why the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in a comment, I think you understanding of "and" is misplaced.

The actual *reason* which people are avoiding is that the first statement actually takes 2 spaces away from each instance, and the second statement never finds any 3-spaced segments, leaving you with (" "... " ")

Therefore the 2-space + 3 space becomes a 1 space + 2 space. (Avoiding typing because spaces are hard to view here)

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out, didn't even think about what you said. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Daftendirekt +1 for answering the question? If it's useful man, if it's useful :p

Comment: I know I am 8 years late, but I gave you your well deserved +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

`element.replace(...)` doesn't modify `element` It just returns a modified version of the string

You could use

```
element = element.replace('   ', ' ')
newelement = element.replace('  ', ' ')
```

It's not a very good general solution though

`str.split()` will group up any amount of whitespace for you, so

```
newelement = ' '.join(element.split())
```

is the easiest way to do this particular task. If you had to remove extra `.` from `"I..like...python"`, you would need another approach